# How do I fix '/wpad.dat' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger, newrelic

I recently added APM to my Rails application running on Phusion Passenger and Nginx.  I am getting flooded with one particular error a consistent call to '/wpad.dat' the volume of which essentially rendering New Relic results useless.

The app is apparently constantly getting pinged for '/wpad.dat' show below.

### The url and http response

- **url:** '/wpad.dat'
- **http response:** 500

### Rails error recorded

[image: error overview in new relic]

I received almost 14K hits to this url in 24 hour window.  It appears to be some sort of service auto discovery.  I was wondering if any one had experience with this issue.  I assume I am missing so setting in nginx or phusion.

### Versions

- **ruby:** 2.2.2
- **rails:** 4.2.1
- **phusion:** 5.0.8
- **nginx:** 1.6.3

Any advice would really be appreciated!

Comment: While it's possible to [ignore different Rails transactions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-configuration/ignoring-specific-transactions) in the New Relic ruby agent, it seems like you have a legitimate 500 error. I'd step through the `StaticPagesController#show` controller code and try to reproduce the issue -- looks like something is `nil` when the code doesn't expect it to be. The [New Relic Ruby Agent forum](https://discuss.newrelic.com/c/ruby-agent) is also a good resource for help with blacklisting certain errors.

Comment: @smithclay The static pages controller is the last route in the routes file, i.e. a catchall so I can have a few vanity urls.  Anything that matches nothing else will eventually fall to static pages controller.  `/ralph` would also throw the same error.  I am not questioning the error, as it makes logical sense.  I am trying to figured out why `/wpad.dat` is being called on my app 14K times per day.  What is the source of this call?  Why is it occurring?  How do I resolve it?

Comment: these are calls from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol , likely it's because lots of machines being configured "DNS Domain" as same as your domain name. You can try to dig the details from you webserver (nginx/apache), and give them a 404 response before they reach your Rails app.